# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: java, sh, processbuilder

Im just trying to test running a shell script thats in my project directory in Eclipse.

```
new ProcessBuilder("scripts/test.sh").start();
```

[image]

Getting this error:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "scripts/test.sh": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Well, if it can't find the file, it would be a good idea to try logging the current working directory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be for two reasons:

- Java execute a system/exec C routine, which except a binary. `test.sh` is **not** a binary. You should probably use bash: `bash -f scripts/test.sh` -> `new ProcessBuilder()("bash", "-f", new File("scripts/test.sh").getAbsoluteFile());`
- The file `scripts/test.sh` does not exists, meaning the current directory is not good.

You can try `System.out.println(new File("scripts/test.sh").getAbsoluteFile())` to print the path Java is using.

Comment: Was trying to run bash script from Java application in windows and getting same error. getAbsoluteFile() enabled JVM to get the bash. Obviously, I installed Cygwin bash previously to get the absolute bash.exe file path in Windows.

Comment: String cmd="scripts/"+scriptName;
String scriptFile = new File(cmd).getAbsoluteFile().getAbsolutePath();
String testcaseNo= fileName.split("\\.")[0];
try { 
String bashFile = PropertyFile.bashFile;
ProcessBuilder processBuilder=new ProcessBuilder(bashFile,"-f",scriptFile + " " + arg0 + " " + arg1);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process bashProcess=processBuilder.start();
bashProcess.waitFor();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Comment: The above code worked for me. The reason as @NoDataFound stated is bash file not being found by Java